# Static interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I do nothing, just create new project then find this error.
pls help me
[image]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is a common issue and you just need to add

```
android {
...
  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
...
}
```

There is explanation and direction in this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/features-of-revolutionary-release-java-8-for-android-d8abe06c34c5)